# Are there other requirements for receiving the Electorate badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I recently noticed that I have exceeded the requirement for the electorate badge, but it has not been awarded and I am curious as to why that might be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description for the Electorate badge says: "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions."

You actually voted on 253 questions, not 600 questions. Voting on 600 questions doesn't mean to vote questions, or for one or more of the answers given to a question; it means to vote a question.

[image: screenshot]

If you voted for 600 questions, and those are all the votes you have casted, you are eligible for the badge; the same is true if you voted 600 questions, and 1800 answers.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I misinterpreted the requirement.  Out of curiosity, why do the badges recognize voting on questions, but not answers?  I would think it important to provide an incentive for doing both.  It seems that few enough do so.

Comment: The badge was introduced to incentive the votes on questions. That is the reason to require that every on four votes one is done for a question.